# mysql.exe flashes and closing immediately

Tags: mysql, sql

I have just installed MySQL 5.0 and tried to open mysql.exe ,it just flashes and closes immediately.
I have set Environment path too and checked at services.msc to ensure MySQL and MySQL57 are started.

Thank You!

Comment: Execute via console and then have a look at the error message.

Comment: It runs as a service in the background. There's not supposed to be anything you can see on the screen. If the service won't start, then you have a problem, but seeing it flash and close right away is normal.